# Rails Serialized Data Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have a field that is serialized to YAML through the default AR behavior. It is currently in an Array of Hashes for examples:

```
[{'name' => 'hi', 'url' => 'bye'}, 
 {'name' => 'hi', 'url' => 'bye'}, 
 {'name' => 'hi', 'url' => 'bye'}]
```

Is there a way I can use some basic AR validations on some of these fields?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, use the `validates_each` method

```
serialize :urls
validates_each :urls do |record, attr, value|
  # value is an array of hashes
  # eg [{'name' => 'hi', 'url' => 'bye'}, ...]

  problems = ''
  if value
    value.each{|name_url| 
      problems << "Name #{name_url['name']} is missing its url. " \
        unless name_url['url']}
  else
    problems = 'Please supply at least one name and url'
  end
  record.errors.add(:urls, problems) unless problems.empty?
end
```

Added: You can't use the validations such as `validates_length_of` since the validation method doesn't understand the format of your serialized field.

The `validates_each` method is good since it enables you to write your own validation method. The method can then add an error to the record if appropriate.

Tip: You can also add an error to the `:base` of record.errors rather than to the specific attribute. Sometimes this can help with the formatting of the error messages in your views.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving this here in case it helps anyone in the future - I've written a gem to better handle validating serialized attributes.  You can just put those validations in a block syntax, the ways you might expect to:

```
serialize :urls
validates_hash_keys :urls do
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true
end
```

https://github.com/brycesenz/validates_serialized

Answer (score 1):

In model

```
store :field_name, :name
store :field_name, :url

validates :name, presence: true
validates :url, presence: true
```

It will provide you attribute accessors also so you can use them like normal fields as:

```
object.name = 'some value' # reader
object.name # writer
object.url = 'some url' # reader
object.url # writer
```